# Index pushing searchbar to the left

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, uisearchcontroller

[image]I have a searchcontroller in a tablview header but it looks like the tableview indexs are causing extra padding on the right. How can I get the left and right padding on the searchcontroller textfield to be the same?

```
var controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    self.controller = ({
            controller.searchResultsUpdater = self
            controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
            controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()
            controller.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
            controller.loadViewIfNeeded()
            controller.delegate = self
            let textFieldInsideSearchBar = controller.searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField
            textFieldInsideSearchBar?.leftViewMode = .always
            textFieldInsideSearchBar?.backgroundColor = "e8e8e9".hexColor
            textFieldInsideSearchBar?.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.whileEditing
            textFieldInsideSearchBar?.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.never
            controller.searchBar.barTintColor = "f6f6f6".hexColor
            self.tableView.tableHeaderView = controller.searchBar
            return controller
        })()
```

[image]

Comment: Are you using layout constraints for your table? It's hard to tell without knowing your sizing and layout methodology.

Comment: yes I am using autolayout for my tableview.

Comment: I added my constraint image to the main post